# jquery zoom with dynamically-changing image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I use `jquery zoom` to display the image of a tshirt and allow my users to zoom it.

Recently, i have added an option to select the color of the t-shirt. After clicking on a color, i have a script that will change the tshirt image with the corresponding color.
The problem is that when a color is selected, the zoomed image will still use the default image (black color).

I need to find a way to tell *jquery.zoom.js* that the image has changed if the user clicked a color

You can test it yourself and see the problem here:
https://www.no-gods-no-masters.com/test.php
Just click on red color then move your mouse over the tshirt - the color is still black.

Source of the jquery plugin used here: https://www.ni-dieu-ni-maitre.com/scripts/jquery.zoom.js

Color-switching script:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: "tshirt_ajax.php?checkshop=" + checkshop + "&checkproducttype=" + checkproducttype + "&stockcolor=" + stockcolor + "&currentsize=" + currentsize,
  beforeSend: function(){
    $('#productColor10462727').val(stockcolor);
  },
  success: function(data){
    $('select#size').html(data);
    $('#tshirtimg').attr('src', 'https://www.ni-dieu-ni-maitre.com/images/16176162_' + stockcolor + '_2/t-shirt-couleur.png');
    $('#size').coreUISelect('update');
  }
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin appends an `img` with CSS class `zoomImg` to the element(s) on which you call `zoom`. One option is to alter the src of this `img`. In your example page, place the following code in the `success` callback.

```
$('#ex1 .zoomImg').attr('src', 'https://www.ni-dieu-ni-maitre.com/images/16176162_' + stockcolor + '_2/t-shirt-couleur.png');
```

This solution, however, depends on the implementation of the plugin. You're probably better off replacing the existing `img` when the user chooses the color, then calling `zoom` on the new `img`.